# Saving lines from a text file to a dynamic array of strings

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is my first year with C, so I am a bit lost.

I have the function:

```
void read(char** lines){

FILE *fpointer = fopen("input1.txt","r");
char *p_input = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
int i,len;
i=0;

lines =  malloc(sizeof(char*));


while( fgets(p_input,200,fpointer) ){ 

    len = strlen(p_input);
    char temp[len];
    strcpy(temp,p_input);
    lines[i] = temp;
    i++;

}
```

}

and in main:

```
int main(){
char **lines;
read(lines);

return 0;}
```

And when I try printing something from the array, I face errors and the code stops, something like:

```
printf("%s\n",lines[0]);
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: You have a few problems in your code. To solve the problem you ask about read about the [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) function. Another problem, which is really bad, is that you save a pointer to a local variable. The variable `temp` will go out of scope and cease to exist for every iteration of the loop. You need to duplicate *the string* and not the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines =  malloc(sizeof(char*));
...
lines[i] = temp;
```

This is wrong, you don't have enough space for an array of pointer to `char`s (you need to know the number of lines to reserve)

Change to something like

```
char **read(void) {
    size_t n = file_lines;
    char **lines =  malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);
    ...
    return lines;
}

int main(void) {
    char **lines;

    lines = read();
    return 0;
}
```

If you dont know the number of lines before-hand you can use `realloc` on each iteration of the `while` loop.

```
char **read(void) {
    ...
    char **lines =  NULL;
    char **tmp;
    ...
    while (fgets(p_input,200,fpointer)) { 
        ...
        tmp = realloc(lines, sizeof(char *) * (i + 1));
        if (tmp != NULL) {
            lines = tmp;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
        lines[i] = temp;
        i++;
    }   
    return lines;
}

int main(void) {
    char **lines;

    lines = read();
    if (lines == NULL) {
        perror("read");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I am trying to stay dynamic, so I don`t prefer to use :                        char **lines =  malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAX_LINES);                                            is there a way to avoid this problem ?

Comment: No, you need to know the number of lines before calling `malloc`, an alternative is `realloc` on each line or a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

In the realloc() example, if you use that together with the original code:

```
while( fgets(p_input,200,fpointer) ){ 
    len = strlen(p_input);
    char temp[len];
...
```

That's a mistake because temp[len] is declared inside the  loop which means it'll be destroyed upon exiting the while loop.  So your entries inside your realloc() array will point to nothing.

You would want to use malloc() inside the while loop to generate a separate space for each entry rather than declare a static array like the above.

And to tidy up at the end remember to free() the space at the end before your program exits completely.